# Python login to website without post method

Tags: python, web-scraping, authentication, screen-scraping

I've been trying for ages to login to a web page to scrape some data with python. I just can't figure out how to perform it after using the Chrome inspect of the login site, it seems different than any of the answers found here. This is the site https://www.weatherlink.com/ and I would need to login to the site and then scrape some data of wind speeds from different public stations.

I've tried with requests library and with multiple different payloads without success. With the following code:

```py
payload = {'username' : 'xx',
           'password': 'yy',
           'localTimezoneOffset': '10800000',
           'keepLogged': ''}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
}

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://www.weatherlink.com/"
result = session_requests.post(login_url, data = payload, headers = headers, verify=True)
```

Expected is `result.ok == True`, but I get False with `reason == "Not allowed"` and `status_code = 405`. After login I would scrape the data from a station e.g from url https://www.weatherlink.com/bulletin/4a891aff-0761-4934-bdf9-9115397c12ea

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the wrong path for the POST request.
Try this:

```py
payload = {
  'username': 'xxx',
  'password': 'yyy',
  'rememberMe': 'false',
  'localTimezoneOffset': '-14400000',
  'ianaTimeZone': 'America/New_York'
}

headers = {
  #you should be able to skip the user-agent string, unless your trying to bypass some kind of anti-bot protection.
}

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://www.weatherlink.com/processLogin"
result = session_requests.post(login_url, data = payload, headers = headers, verify=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it did not work for me, but the error message with your suggestion is "Forbidden" with status_code 403. Did you manage to login successfully with that?